# Unable to add a link inside the summary tag in GitHub flavored markdown

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown, readme

Considering the below markdown code, what I would like to do is target the `<summary id="stage-one">Stage 1</summary>` from inside the Stage 3 content as such `[Link to Stage 1](#stage-one)`.

The issue with this approach is that VS code says **No definition** for the id **stage-one**.

```
<details>

  <summary id="stage-one">Stage 1</summary>

  * Vegetables

  * Fruits

  * Fish

</details>

 
<details>

  <summary id="stage-two">Stage 2</summary>

  * Vegetables

  * Fruits

  * Fish

</details>


<details>

  <summary id="stage-three">Stage 3</summary>

  * Vegetables

  * Fruits

  * Fish

  * [Link to Stage 1](#stage-one)

</details>
```

Tried using the anchor tag `<a href="#stage-one">**Stage 1**</a>` instead of `[Link to Stage 1](#stage-one)` but faced the same issue.

Is there a way to implement this approach in markdown language?

Comment: Where are you trying to render it? In VSCode or on GitHub?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Seems this is valid markdown and [produces the desired HTML](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=%3Cdetails%3E%0A%20%20%3Csummary%20id%3D%22stage-one%22%3EStage%201%3C%2Fsummary%3E%0A%0A%20%20*%20Vegetables%0A%20%20*%20Fruits%0A%20%20*%20Fish%0A%3C%2Fdetails%3E%0A%0Aa%0A%0Ab%0A%0Ac%0A%0Ad%0A%0Ae%0A%0Af%0A%0Ag%0A%0Ah%0A%0A%0A%3Cdetails%3E%0A%20%20%3Csummary%20id%3D%22stage-three%22%3EStage%203%3C%2Fsummary%3E%0A%0A%20%20*%20Vegetables%0A%20%20*%20%5BLink%20to%20Stage%201%5D(%23stage-one)%0A%3C%2Fdetails%3E%0A)... where do you get "No definition for the id"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is working. However, your example yields a page too small to perceive the result. Add sufficient page content between `id="stage-one">` and your `[Link to Stage 1](#stage-one)` so that you have to scroll the former (`id="stage-one">`) out-of-view (off the page) when you click on the later (`[Link to Stage 1](#stage-one)`). Then you should see that it scrolls up to the former, as you desire.